# Laravel Passport auth code redirection uri

Tags: laravel, next.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, laravel-passport

I am basically using a NEXT JS app which runs on port 3005 as the application and Laravel as the Authorization Server which runs on port 5001.

I understand I have to create a client for my Next JS App which I named it as Application 1 which I have gotten the client id and secret , my redirection uri would be http://localhost:3005/auth/callback

The callback component is a simple component which exists in pages/auth/callback

```
import React from "react";

const callback = () => {
  return <div>Here I am in call back url</div>;
};

export default callback;
```

The next step is to do a GET request and get the auth code from my authorization server which exists in port 5001.

So I formed this url,

```
http://localhost:5001/oauth/authorize?client_id=3&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3005/auth/callback&response_type=code&scope=seed_payment&state=1kQKfEnidW8KB0CDr12bTOgWmRHadKO23Wr4nO4v&prompt=login
```

So what happens is that it prompts me to login

[image]

Then asks me to authorize

[image]

Which I click authorize , it doesn't redirect me to my url, instead the callback component exists in a iframe in the http://localhost:5001/login . How do I make it to redirect to my redirect_uri which is http://localhost:3005/auth/callback . The Login page that I am using in http://localhost:5001 is laravel breeze.

Please help , thank you

[image]